# Filtered query_vars becomes global. Why does this work?

Tags: filters, globals, query-variable

For some reason that's not quite clear, when I add custom query_vars, they become available everywhere without the need of an accessor like `global` or `get_query_var()`

```
// if your url contains the var http://example.com?document_id=99
// and you add it to $query_vars...
<?php
function filter__query_vars( $query_vars ) {
  $query_vars[] = 'document_id';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'filter__query_vars' );

// you can reference it anywhere.
/* single.php */
<?php
echo $document_id; // outputs 99. wtf?
```

Why does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the `WP::parse_request()` method ([src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/711796d17256a370a08ead0ecf65278630311efd/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L294)) we locate the `query_vars` filter:

```
$this->public_query_vars = apply_filters( 'query_vars', $this->public_query_vars );
```

and within `WP::register_globals()` we can see  **why** it becomes globally accessible ([src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/711796d17256a370a08ead0ecf65278630311efd/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L577-L580)):

```
// Extract updated query vars back into global namespace.
foreach ( (array) $wp_query->query_vars as $key => $value ) {
    $GLOBALS[ $key ] = $value;
}
```

where the global `$Wp_query` has been fed with the query vars from the global `$wp` object.

Comment: This is the correct answer. By design, and history, and legacy code, query_vars are inherently global. They affect the query. The query is a global thing. If you don't want them global, don't make them query_vars. Additionally, if they don't directly affect the main WP_Query, then definitely don't make them query_vars.

Comment: It looks like it's possible to override the global `$wp_query` and `$wp` objects through the `query_vars` filter with `wp_query` and `wp` as new custom query variables ;-) Maybe there should be a check for that to avoid total crash? @Otto

Comment: No, there needs to be no check for that. Simply don't do that. You can override a lot of things the wrong way and thus break everything, but then you broke everything and it doesn't work, so what would be the point?

Comment: yes, good point, too many ways to break things up anyway, like the globals  ;-) @Otto

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @birgire. I get it now.
[@]Otto, this wasn't a problem, I just wanted to know why it worked.