# How does the $post_type global variable work?

Tags: custom-post-types, variables, customization, globals

I need to output the name of the custom post type within archive.php and single.php.

I would use something like this:

```
if ( 'staff' == get_post_type() ) {

$post_type = 'staff';

}

echo '<div class="'.$post_type.'">Content</div>';
```

This would give me the required result of `<div class="staff">`

However, it appears I can also access the global variable called `$post_type` and simply output this on archive.php or single.php even without declaring `global`, for example this archives the same result as above:

```
<div class="<?php echo $post_type; ?>">
```

Codex says the global variable `$post_type` is for use within the Wordpress admin area.

My questions are:

1. Why does `$post_type` work without declaring it globally first?
2. Is it a good idea to use the `$post_type` global var as demonstrated above for use in theme templates?

Thank you

Comment: Does it work when you are logged out too?

Comment: It's the same behaviour logged in or logged out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global `$post_type` is usually from the public query variable of the main query `$wp_query`, but `get_post_type()` is the post type of the current `$post` object, within the loop.

So for e.g. secondary loops this can be different.

The global `$post_type` might not always be set, as the default post type for `WP_Query` is the `post` post type.

From  `WP::register_globals()` we can see how the `post_type` query variable becomes globally accessible:

```
// Extract updated query vars back into global namespace.
foreach ( (array) $wp_query->query_vars as $key => $value ) {
    $GLOBALS[ $key ] = $value;
}
```

as I posted in my recent answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/264185/26350).

In general I would use the WordPress API calls,  instead of using direct globals, as the former usually is designed to handle various cases, including defaults, and is updated when needed.

Working directly with the globals increases the risk of overriding them.

If your goal is to setup some CSS selectors, one can often just use the ones provided for the `<body>` tag, with the `body_class()` core function. Also consider the [`post_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/) core function, within your loop, as it already contains the post type class info.